# To update the content of the table in Sqlite Database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a database in Sqlite Android Application, there are two fields in the table i.e **Name and Email**. I want to update the contents of the table, the query that i am using is.

```
db.update(TABLENAME,cv,"id=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(7)});
```

As this will update the content that have the ID 7, but i want to update the table by matching the name entered.

Answer (score 1):

Add another Parameter like

```
db.update(TABLENAME,cv,"id=? AND Name=? ",new String[]{String.valueOf(7),NameValue});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String where="id=? and Name=?";
db.update(TABLENAME,cv,where,new String[]{String.valueOf(7),NameValue});
```

Answer (score 0):

pass your string array in update method...

```
public int Upadte(String name_value,String email_value,String new_name) {
    ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
    value.put("name",new_name);
    return _sqliteDB.update(TABLE_NAME ,value," NAME "+"=?"+" and "+" EMAIL "+"=?",new String[]{name_value,email_value});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To match the name instead of the ID, just replace the column name in the `whereClause`:

```java
db.update(TABLENAME, cv, "Name=?", new String[]{"PanKush"});
```